# Insert List of dictionary data into SQL Server using pytds tvp

Tags: python, sql-server, table-valued-parameters, sqlalchemy-pytds

I would like to implement list of dict data to be loaded into SQL Server DB using `pytds` tablevalueparams `tvp` in my python code. \

I tried below mentioned code and it's not working as expected.

```
def call_sproc(val):
    server = 'my_server'
    user = 'my_user'
    password = 'secret'
    database = 'my_db'
    
    try:
        conn = pytds.connect(server=server, user=user, password=password, database=database)
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        tvp = pytds.TableValuedParam(type_name='dbo.tbl', rows=val)
        cursor.callproc("dbo.stproc", (tvp,))
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

    except pytds.Error as e:
        print("Connection issue:", e)

###
val=[{'id': 'st001', 'name':'abc'}, {'id': 'st002', 'name':'pqr'}, {'id': 'st003', 'name':'xyz'}]
call_sproc(val)
```

**Error: **

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:/Users/mydesk/Desktop/test/insertpytds.py", line 60, in 
> connect_and_call_stored_procedure(val)
> File "c:/Users/mydesk/Desktop/test/insertpytds.py", line 23, in call_sproc
> cursor.callproc("[dbo].[stproc]", (tvp,))
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytds_*init*_.py", line 597, in callproc
> return self.*callproc(procname, parameters)
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytds_*init**.py", line 562, in _callproc
> self._exec_with_retry(lambda: self.*session.submit_rpc(procname, parameters, 0))
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytds_*init**.py", line 668, in *exec_with_retry
>
> return fun()
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytds_*init**.py", line 562, in 
> self._exec_with_retry(lambda: self._session.submit_rpc(procname, parameters, 0))
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytds\tds.py", line 1032, in submit_rpc
> serializer.write(w, param.value)
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytds\tds_types.py", line 2302, in write
> self._columns_serializers[i].write(w, row[I])
> KeyError: 0

I tried with list of tuples and it is working fine. But due to the risk in inserting the data wrongly in DB columns when interchange the positions in data (ex: interchange col1 to col3). I suppose list of dict data can be properly fit as per the keys in DB cols.

Comment: Assuming `TableValuedParam` accepts a list of dictionaries (PyTDS documentation is ... scarce), it will expect one dictionary per row with all columns, not one per cell.

Comment: None of [the unit tests](https://github.com/denisenkom/pytds/blob/bf6743506451c5909e411b36aeeefda105707058/tests/unit_test.py#L863) uses dictionaries and the [source code](https://github.com/denisenkom/pytds/blob/bf6743506451c5909e411b36aeeefda105707058/src/pytds/tds_types.py#L2300) iterates over the row values by index which means you can't use dictionaries. The [TableValuedParam](https://github.com/denisenkom/pytds/blob/bf6743506451c5909e411b36aeeefda105707058/src/pytds/tds_types.py#L2162) source shows it accepts a `columns` parameter though, that can be used to specify column names

Comment: HI @PanagiotisKanavos, Thanks for your response. 
Is it possible to share an example to specify `columns`?

Comment: Try passing either a tuple or a list of column names. As I said, the documentation is scarce, so are the help strings and the source has no types. You'll have to try and see.